# csv.writerows() writing one character to each row

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv

e = {'description':'The remote host is missing AIX', 'script_version': '$Revision: 1.4 $', 'plugin_modification_date':'2011/03/14'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = e.keys()
    v = e.values()

    print k
    print v

    with open('poop2.csv', 'w') as g:
        writer = csv.writer(g)
        for v in e:
            writer.writerows(v)
```

this is a sample of what my csv looks like

```
d
e
s
c
```

and so forth to match all the characters in `keys`.

Comment: For the future -- you need to create a **minimal, complete, verifiable** example for a question about code to be relevant here. This is a Q&A site, not a debugging service. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ...so, f'rinstance, if you have a question about CSV generation, you should provide code that does **nothing but** CSV generation. Also, to be "complete" and "verifiable", that needs to include everything anyone else would need to run it -- no calling out to random web services nobody else will have.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy understood, im in the process of recreating code now.. thank you

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , i think that should be better and thanks again .

Comment: Much better indeed. I've done a tiny bit more cleanup to remove extra imports and use a more descriptive title, but this is good enough to be answerable. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`csv.writerows(v)` expects `v` to be a sequence of rows. Instead, the `v` being passed in is a single string -- a sequence of characters, not a sequence of rows. Thus, you get one character to each row.

Putting `csv.writerow([v])` inside your loop would more likely be what you want.

---

If you wanted to put keys and values next to each other, by the way, I'd iterate over pairs rather than splitting keys and values out ahead-of-time:

```
for k, v in e.iteritems():
  writer.writerow([k, v])
```

---

By contrast, to generate two rows, the first with keys, the second with values:

```
writer.writerow(e.keys())
writer.writerow(e.values())
```

Comment: Or even `writer.writerows(e.items())` looks viable

Comment: @Charles Duffy how do i make it look like this `plugin_modification_date,description,script_version \n
2011/03/14,The remote host is missing AIX,$Revision: 1.4 $`

Comment: @wwi, amended the answer appropriately. (You might want to describe desired output in the question, next time).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy "['2011/03/14', 'The remote host is missing AIX', '$Revision: 1.4 $']"   ok , this is awesome so far, how would i remove the qoutes and brackets?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your amended answer gave me the desired output.